# WebMethod Returning DataSet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, dataset, webmethod

I've the following WebMethod that returns a DataSet:

```
'A method to select all records in Eqp_For_Sale table
    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function RetrieveAllFromEqp_For_Sale() As DataSet

    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebDB_ConnectionString").ToString)
        conn.Open()

    Dim comm As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Eqp_For_Sale")

    comm.Connection = conn

    Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    da.SelectCommand = comm

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    da.Fill(ds)

    conn.Close()

    Return ds
End Function
```

I called this WebMethod from a new VB.NET application to retrieve the data, and I used the following code to retrive it into a DataGridView:

```
Dim a As New UsedEqpWS.UsedEqpWSSoapClient

DataGridView1.DataSource = a.RetrieveAllFromEqp_For_Sale
```

But the problem is when I click the button that calls these three lines, the DataGridView simply shows nothing. I tried to call the same WebMethod from a new ASP.NET Website and it working perfectly there.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
a.RetrieveAllFromEqp_For_Sale.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Hwah, you saved my life! Thanks a lot Andy.